# Get a certain combination of numbers in Python

Tags: python-3.x, math, equation

Is there a efficient and convenient solution in Python to do something like -

Find largest combination of two numbers `x` and `y`, with the following conditions -

```
0 < x < 1000 
0 < y < 2000
x/y = 0.75
x & y are integers
```

It's easy to do it using a simple graphing calculator but trying to find the best way to do it in Python

Comment: The problem is a simple math. Of course, you can solve it with python in several lines of code. What effieciency and convinience do you expect?

Comment: Will it involve any loops?

Comment: What does largest combination mean?

Comment: means out of all the possible combinations of x and y that satisfy those conditions, i want the pair whose sum is the greatest

Comment: @Varun Depends on the implementation. I would use two for-loops explicitly. I guess one may use `itertools` functions to hide any looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pulp  

My_optimization_prob = pulp.LpProblem('My_Optimization_Problem', pulp.LpMaximize) 

# Creating the variables
x = pulp.LpVariable("x", lowBound = 1, cat='Integer') 
y = pulp.LpVariable("y", lowBound = 1, cat='Integer') 

# Adding the Constraints
My_optimization_prob  += x + y #Maximize X and Y
My_optimization_prob  += x <= 999 # x < 1000
My_optimization_prob  += y <= 1999 # y < 2000
My_optimization_prob  += x - 0.75*y == 0 # x/y = 0.75


#Printing the Problem and Constraints
print(My_optimization_prob) 

My_optimization_prob.solve()  
#printing X Y
print('x = ',pulp.value(x))
print('y = ',pulp.value(y))
```

Comment: thank you saif, I wonder what is the time complexity of this solution

Comment: it should be constant.

Comment: thank you, would like to suggest one edit - 

x = pulp.LpVariable("x", lowBound = 1, cat='Integer')
y = pulp.LpVariable("y", lowBound = 1, cat='Integer')

Answer (score 0):

Probably just -

```
z = [(x, y) for x in range(1, 1000) for y in range(1, 2000) if x/y==0.75]
z.sort(key=lambda x: sum(x), reverse=True)
z[0]
#Returns (999, 1332)
```

This is convenient, not sure if this is the most efficient way.

Comment: I guess ratio must be equal to 3/4 not less then.

Comment: I would replace `x/y == .75` with `4 * x == 3 * y` because floating point arithmetic cannot be always accurate.

Comment: thank you, am I right to say that the time complexity of this solution is O(n^2)?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible relatively efficient solution is -

```
x_upper_limit = 1000
y_upper_limit = 2000
x = 0
y = 0
temp_variable = 0
ratio = 0.75

for i in range(x_upper_limit, 0, -1):
    temp_variable = i/ratio
    if temp_variable.is_integer() and temp_variable < y_upper_limit:
        x = i
        y = int(temp_variable)
        break

print(x,y)
```